# GUI updates from another thread using CallAfter in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

I am working on a small Desktop Application in C++ using wxWidgets, it is about visualizing different types of sorting. In order to keep GUI responsive while the sorting is taking place and being drawn on the screen I am trying to do some work on a different thread, but I know that GUI updates must take place from the main thread - so I found a tutorial in which `CallAfter` was used so that GUI was updated from the main thread. However, the result I am getting is that the table is being sorted almost immediately (by worker thread) and gets displayed on screen but the GUI freezes for some time and gets updated a lot (nothing changes on the screen as the table gest sorted at the beginning).

Some of the code Im talking about:

```
#include "GUIMyFrame1.h"

GUIMyFrame1::GUIMyFrame1(wxWindow* parent)
    :
    MyFrame1(parent), _maxElemValue{ 25 }
{
    UpdateTabSize();
    Draw();
}

void GUIMyFrame1::drawPanelOnSize(wxSizeEvent& event)
{
    Draw();

}

void GUIMyFrame1::m_slider_Num_of_ElemOnScroll(wxScrollEvent& event)
{
    _maxElemValue = _tab.size();
    UpdateTabSize();
    Draw();

}

void GUIMyFrame1::m_button_SortOnButtonClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    auto f = [this]() {
        for (int i = 0; i < _tab.size() - 1; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < _tab.size() - i - 1; j++) {

                wxGetApp().CallAfter([this, j] {
                    Draw();
                    });

                if (_tab[j + 1] < _tab[j])
                    std::swap(_tab[j + 1], _tab[j]);
            }
        wxGetApp().CallAfter([this] {
            Draw();
        });
    };

    std::thread worker(f);

    worker.detach();
}

void GUIMyFrame1::m_button_ShuffleOnButtonClick(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    UpdateTabSize();
    Draw();
}

void GUIMyFrame1::Draw()
{
    wxClientDC dc1(drawPanel);
    wxBufferedDC dc(&dc1);

    dc.Clear();

    int w, h;

    drawPanel->GetSize(&w, &h);

    int tempWidth = w / _tab.size();
    double unitHeight = (double)h / _maxElemValue;

    int shift = GetShift(w);

    for (int i = 0; i < _tab.size(); i++) {
        wxBrush tempBrush(_tab[i]._color);
        wxPen tempPen(_tab[i]._color, 0);

        dc.SetBrush(tempBrush);
        dc.SetPen(tempPen);

        dc.DrawRectangle(
            wxRect(
                shift + i * tempWidth, h - (int)(unitHeight * _tab[i]._value) + 2,
                tempWidth, (int)(unitHeight * _tab[i]._value) - 4
            ));
    }
}

void GUIMyFrame1::UpdateTabSize()
{
    _tab.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < m_slider_Num_of_Elem->GetValue(); i++)
        _tab.push_back(getNewRandomElement(_maxElemValue));
}

int GUIMyFrame1::GetShift(int w) {
    int AllElemWidth = _tab.size() * int(w / _tab.size());
    return (w - AllElemWidth) / 2;
}
```

My question is how do I fix that? I guess the whole drawing process is taking much longer than every comparison in sorting but why don't the GUI updates stop as soon as the table gest sorted? I did try `std::mutex` as I thought the synchronization might help, because `_tab` might be changed and read at the same time while sorting and drawing to screen but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your program would work just fine if you simply replace calls to `Draw()` inside `CallAfter()` with the calls to `Refresh()` -- and only actually draw your window from your `wxEVT_PAINT` handler which is the only really supported and portable way to do it.

Comment: So I connected `wxEVT_PAINT` to `drawPanelOnPaint()` method (`drawPanel->Connect( wxEVT_PAINT, wxPaintEventHandler( MyFrame1::drawPanelOnPaint ), NULL, this );`) and moved code to it from `Draw()` method. At first, the result I got was that the GUI didn't freeze anymore, however, the `drawPanel` became all black without any elements being painted on it. I tried `Refresh(false)` (_If true, the background will be erased._) and it worked, I'm not sure why but I'm glad it did.

Comment: One more thing - when there is no delay (`std::this_thread::sleep_for`) between comparisons in bubble sort or it is smaller than 200ns the `Refresh()` gets called only once resulting in immediately going from unsorted to sorted table. But that might be just because drawing the frame on the screen takes more than 200ns, right? Anyway, thank you a lot for helping me find the solution!

Answer (score 0):

to make it look appealing you can use a [condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) where the worker will `wait` on it after every `callafter` and the main thread will finish drawing then `notify_one` on it so the worker will then continue sorting.

You will get exactly one frame for each modification, feel free to add an extra [sleep](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) in the worker till the result is appealing enough.